# Is it a good ball or inbound violation?

Tags: rules, nba, fiba

In basketball, let's say a player is inbounding the ball, tosses the basketball at the referee who’s inside the playing court, and the same player takes the ball back to action afterwards.

It is a good ball or violation?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered by [NBA Rules](https://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2022/10/Official-Playing-Rules-2022-23-NBA-Season.pdf) Rule 10, Section III

> **A thrower-in shall not** (1) carry the ball onto the court; (2) fail to release the ball within 5
> seconds; (3) **touch it on the court before it has touched another player;** (4) leave the designated
> throw-in spot which is one step to his left or right; (5) throw the ball so that it enters the
> basket before touching anyone on the court; (6) step on the court over the boundary line before
> the ball is released; (7) throw the ball out-of-bounds without it being touched by a player
> in the game; (8) exit the playing surface to gain an advantage on a throw-in; (9) hand the ball
> to a player on the court.

> PENALTY: Loss of ball. The ball is awarded to the opposing team at the original spot of
> the throw-in.

The referee is not a player and does not satisfy the prohibition for clause (3).  This is a violation and the opposing team gets the ball.

[FIBA Rules](https://www.fiba.basketball/documents/official-basketball-rules/current.pdf) are very similar here, and the corresponding section is 17.3.1.